How to efficiently initialize pinia state like user auth in nuxt3 via api call
I have a nuxt 3 app, I use pinia to manage the user authentication state.
I defined the store like this
interface AuthUser {
    id: number;
    username: string;
    email: string;
    roles: string[];
}

export const useAuthStore = defineStore(
    'auth', () => {
        const user = ref<AuthUser | null>(null)
        const isAuthenticated = ref(false);
        const isLoading = ref(false);

        async function fetchProfile() {
            isLoading.value = true;
            try {
                const response = await fetch(AUTH_API.PROFILE, {
                    method: 'GET',
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    },
                    credentials: 'include',
                });
                const data = await response.json() as { message: string, data: AuthUser };
                if (response.ok && data.message === 'success') {
                    user.value = data.data;
                    isAuthenticated.value = true;
                }
                isLoading.value = false;
                return data;
            } catch (error) {
                isLoading.value = false;
                return { message: 'error', data: error };
            }
        }

        async function login(email: string, password: string) {
            try {
                const response = await fetch(AUTH_API.LOGIN, {
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    },
                    credentials: 'include',
                    body: JSON.stringify({
                        email,
                        password,
                    }),
                });
                const data = await response.json() as { message: string, data: AuthUser };
                if (response.ok && data.message === 'success') {
                    user.value = data.data;
                    isAuthenticated.value = true;
                }
                return data;
            } catch (error) {
                return { message: 'error', data: error };
            }
        }

        async function register(email: string, password: string) {
            try {
                const response = await fetch(AUTH_API.REGISTER, {
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    },
                    credentials: 'include',
                    body: JSON.stringify({
                        email,
                        password,
                    }),
                });
                const data = await response.json() as { message: string, data: AuthUser };
                if (response.ok && data.message === 'success') {
                    user.value = data.data;
                    isAuthenticated.value = true;
                }
                return data;
            } catch (error) {
                return { message: 'error', data: error };
            }
        }

        async function logout() {
            try {
                const response = await fetch(AUTH_API.LOGOUT, {
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    },
                    credentials: 'include',
                });
                const data = await response.json() as { message: string };
                if (response.ok && data.message === 'success') {
                    user.value = null;
                    isAuthenticated.value = false;
                }
                return data;
            } catch (error) {
                return { message: 'error', data: error };
            }
        }

        return { user, isAuthenticated, isLoading, fetchProfile, register, login, logout }
    }
)

I would like to call the fetchProfile() only once during app startup or when something goes wrong ( for some reason state changed, and want to refetch ).
Where is the best place to call it like that ?
When I tried calling in a protected layout like this,
const authStore = useAuthStore();

useAsyncData(async () => {
  await authStore.fetchProfile();
});

It loads only when I navigate to the protected layout 2nd time.
Still searching for the efficient way to do this ( I'm using nuxtjs for SSG )
